# Telethon TypeError when using EditBannedRequests

Tags: python, typeerror, telegram-bot, telethon

what I want to do is: A User enter the chat by an invite link and get checkt in an extra chat (1n1 with the bot) with a captcha. I read EditBannedRequest should do what I want but... I get an type error.
My EditBannedRequest is for now basicly the example from the
[docs](https://arabic-telethon.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/chats-and-channels.html)...
So would be nice if someone can help.

The Code:

```
async def handler(event):
    chat = await event.get_chat()
        
    if isinstance(event.action_message.action, types.MessageActionChatJoinedByLink):
        global acitve_invite_link
        chat_to_add = await bot.get_entity('TestyTesyChatty')
        result = await bot(ExportChatInviteRequest(chat_to_add.id))
        acitve_invite_link = False
        temp = await bot.get_entity(event.action_message.from_id)
        await bot(EditBannedRequest(
                chat, temp, ChatBannedRights(
                    until_date=None,
                    view_messages=True
                )
        ))
...
```

The Error:

```
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Handling RPC result for message 6884206512220131084
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Handling acknowledge for [6884206512264014408]
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Receiving items from the network...
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Handling RPC result for message 6884206512264014408
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Receiving items from the network...
DEBUG:telethon.extensions.messagepacker:Assigned msg_id = 6884206512487415476 to GetUsersRequest (20efd6344c0)
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Encrypting 1 message(s) in 44 bytes for sending
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Encrypted messages put in a queue to be sent
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Waiting for messages to send...
DEBUG:telethon.extensions.messagepacker:Assigned msg_id = 6884206512491466684 to MsgsAck (20efd634910)
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Encrypting 1 message(s) in 60 bytes for sending
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Encrypted messages put in a queue to be sent
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Waiting for messages to send...
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Handling RPC result for message 6884206512487415476
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Receiving items from the network...
ERROR:telethon.client.updates:Unhandled exception on handler
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Just\a\Path\Python\Python38\site-packages\telethon\client\updates.py", line 443, in _dispatch_update
    await callback(event)
  File "C:\Just\another\path\telegram\enter_bot.py", line 191, in handler
    await bot(EditBannedRequest(
  File "C:\Just\a\Path\Python\Python38\site-packages\telethon\client\users.py", line 30, in __call__  
    return await self._call(self._sender, request, ordered=ordered)
  File "C:\Just\a\Path\Python\Python38\site-packages\telethon\client\users.py", line 37, in _call     
    await r.resolve(self, utils)
  File "C:\Just\a\Path\Python\Python38\site-packages\telethon\tl\functions\channels.py", line 304, in 
resolve
    self.channel = utils.get_input_channel(await client.get_input_entity(self.channel))
  File "C:\Just\a\Path\Python\Python38\site-packages\telethon\utils.py", line 263, in get_input_channel
    _raise_cast_fail(entity, 'InputChannel')
  File "C:\Just\a\Path\Python\Python38\site-packages\telethon\utils.py", line 138, in _raise_cast_fail
    raise TypeError('Cannot cast {} to any kind of {}.'.format(
TypeError: Cannot cast InputPeerChat to any kind of InputChannel.
INFO:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Disconnecting from 149.154.167.51:443/TcpFull...
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Closing current connection...
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Cancelling 0 pending message(s)...
INFO:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Disconnection from 149.154.167.51:443/TcpFull complete!
INFO:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Not disconnecting (already have no connection)
```

Also another question:

1. The user should get muted -> press a button
2. Get a question in a direct message -> if wrong get kicked
3. If right, then should get unmuted

How would 3. work in this example. I mean I set a time in

```
ChatBannedRights(
                    until_date=None,
                    view_messages=True
                )
        ))
```

until_date does it mean the user get after that muted again? Or is there a possibility to do that for ever?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Telegram does not support EditBannedRights in a chat, only in a supergroup. Go to an official Telegram client and change history for new members to visible, and then your code will work. Also, you ought to change chat to event.get_input_chat()

Comment: Worth mentioning that there is a friendly method for this, [`client.edit_permissions`](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/modules/client.html#telethon.client.chats.ChatMethods.edit_permissions), which documents this behaviour: *"The channel or megagroup where the restriction should happen."*.